# onCLICK with multiple variables

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, function, onclick

Please help me to create a function which includes multiple variables - at least two...

I have a table which it was created with PHP and MySQL... all IDs were dinamically created that why I need to Catch them other way rather to specify them.

A small piece of CODE for better understanding the structure of table - I have included in [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sirgenius/UcCeW/30/)

```
function delete_id(id) {
    alert (id);
    var test = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(test);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var test = $('#'+id).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

`$(this)` in your function does not mean what you think. You need to use the `id` that you passed into the `function` and get that element with `$('#'+id)`

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhXkh/)**

Answer (score 1):

I believe using an delegate with on method is good use here. As if we use this, its not going to bubble the event to document as well as its not going to create as many click handlers for all the tr's or a tags under those dynamic tr's in the DOM which overall is good for performance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ultomonitor').on('click','a', function(){
    alert("id of div under a " + $(this).children().attr('id'));
    alert("id of tr above a " + $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps5Wn/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Better Approach

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UcCeW/31/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><div id="8928392" onclick="delete_id(this)"
```

**js**

```
function delete_id(el) {
    var test = $(el).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(test);
};
```

or

Pure JavaScript Approach

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UcCeW/32/)

```
function delete_id(el) {
    var test = getNearestTableRowAncestor(el).id;
    alert(test);
};

function getNearestTableRowAncestor(htmlElementNode) {
    while (htmlElementNode) {
        htmlElementNode = htmlElementNode.parentNode;
        if (htmlElementNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr') {
            return htmlElementNode;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: i need to keep this simple for a Jquery/Ajax function - thank you very much for your approach!!!

Comment: @SergiuCostas this is better approach than the answer --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UcCeW/31/

Comment: In my case, I needed both IDs... the answer gave me the solution to receive in function both IDs... in your case - I got only the ID from <TR>... But anyway nice approach.. thank you very much! I would learn from your experience!!!

Comment: @SergiuCostas check this out http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UcCeW/33/ just you have to use `el.id` to get id

Comment: Indeed! it works! But I have already gave my Answer to @Sergio because he offered promptly a nice acceptable solution which satisfied the question. Your approach is nice too. Thank you once more time!!!